# android real add is not showing with sdk 17.1.3

Tags: android, admob

i am trying to show banner ad in my app...for that i followed the below steps

1. adding dependencies in app level 17.1.3
2. adding layout file and java code as per the instruction.
3. adding manifests tag

   but `com.google.android.gm.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP`
   is showing test add successfully,but not the real ad even after publish it in play store.if i use `APPLICATION_ID` instead of `AD_MANAGER_APP` than the app is crashing and providing error `'follow the proper instructions'.`

N.B here i can't show my code and may be my problem is also not clear.some of the cases showing me error and preventing me not to post so please try to help me and not mark it duplicate.

Comment: you are using admob right ?

Comment: yes,implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'

Comment: have you changes your banner id to live  id

Comment: yes,i change it...

Comment: have you register payment method in admob console ?

Comment: no,i didn't register.

Comment: dont worry . i'm attaching one reference [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/) . please verify with your code.. If you are still facing issue . please post code with error you are getting

Comment: 1.MainActivity.java
   MobileAds.initialize(this,
                "ca-app-pub-9586807215639015~3539666244");
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewforcalendar);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);.

Comment: 2.activity_main.xml
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adViewforcalendar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit"
        >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

Comment: 3.build.gradle(moudle:app)
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
4.manifests
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-9586807215639015~3539666244" />

Comment: I am here providing my oroginal id.there is no error just not showing any real ad.